# Redireccionar Input y output de subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy intentando hacer un estilo de linea de comandos que se comunica con la nativa del SO (bash, pwsh, zsh, etc.)

```
App.py -> Input (función nativa input() de Python)
   ^        |
   |        v
Output <- Bash
   |
   v
(función print() de Python)
```

Para esto se me ocurre usar subprocess ya que se que puede generar procesos y comunicarlos pero no se como hacerlo hasta ahora tengo esto

```py
running = True
while running:
    cmd = input("cmd> ")
    if cmd in ['exit','quit']:
        running = False
    else:
        # Logica de subprocess?
```

Comment: ¿Ese código es todo lo que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: Si, en realidad falta una parte que detecta si el comando empieza con $ si es el caso lo ejecuta como comando de bash si no ejecuta el comando como si fuera del programa